# Flutter [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(39)] PlatformException(sign_in_failed, com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 10: )

Tags: android, flutter, google-signin

I want to set up a Google login with Flutter.
In Firebase I have the SHA's for both debug and realease.
When I start the app I get the button and it lets me enter the email, but when I press enter I get this error:

> E/flutter (24342): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(39)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(sign_in_failed, com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 10: , null, null)

I have tried other published solutions but I still get this error.  I have tried both on the emulator and on the physical device.
The file google-services.json is inside the app folder.

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
 
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  google_sign_in: ^5.3.3
  provider: ^6.0.3
  firebase: ^9.0.3
  firebase_core: ^1.17.1
  firebase_auth: ^3.3.19
  firebase_database: ^9.0.15
```

I try to run the app locally on an emulator.
in many of the solutions I see that the app is uploaded to google. is it not possible to test it locally?

Comment: please edit your question and include [example]